# Stream from WCF method is not correct when invoked from unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wcf

I have a wcf service as following:

```
public class DocumentReadService : IDocumentReader
{
    public Stream GetDocument(string docName)
    {
        //read file
        if (WebOperationContext.Current != null)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        }
        //return file stream
    }
}
```

But when I do unit test(using moq) the above method, I don't get expected stream which is a pdf if saved to a file.

Meaning the pdf should be same as that of what I get when I browse the same wcf service hosted url.

Could anybody give me some advice about this issue?

Comment: Fixed some typos and reworded a bit

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, Issue was with the way stream was saved to file in unit test. It should be done with BinaryWriter as following and not as normal stream save to file,

```
Stream serviceResult = documentReaderMock.GetDocument("abc");

using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(_sourceFilePath + "\\DownloadedFile.pdf",(int)serviceResult.Length))
{
  BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
  byte[] bytesInStream = new byte[serviceResult.Length];
  serviceResult.Read(bytesInStream, 0, bytesInStream.Length);
  bw.Write(bytesInStream);
  bw.Close();
}
```